# Batch File Replace/Rename

Tags: batch-file

I am looking to rename a bunch of files in a directory with a batch file.  I want to do this:

file_XX_img.tiff to file_32_img.tiff

I have this code

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set fName=%1
if '%1' equ '' set /p fName=Enter file name:


for /f "delims==" %%F in ('dir /b *.aaa') do ren "%%~nxF" "%%~nF"

pause
```

that renames the extension but I want to convert it so I can replace the XX with a number.  How do I modify it to work for this situation?

----------------------------------EDIT---------------------------------------------

figured it out:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set fName=%1
set /p vers=Enter Vers:
for /f "delims==" %%F in ('dir /b file_XX*.*') do ren "%%~nxF" "file_%vers%*.*"
pause
```

Comment: You can answer your own question with what you figured out : )

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of issues with your solution.

1. The `%1` parameter is stored into the `fname` variable, but is never used actually.
2. Renaming files like that will work as expected only for 2-digit values of `vers`. If it was 1 digit, the result would be like `file_3X_img.tif`. If it was more than 2 digits, you'd have something like this (for 4 digits): `file_3210mg.tif`.

I guess your solution may still fit you for some time (maybe, until you reach 100). Nevertheless, you might want to consider the following alternative:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "vers=%~1"
IF "%vers%" == "" SET /P "vers=Enter Vers: "
FOR %%F IN (file_XX_*.*) DO CALL :process "%%F"
GOTO :EOF

:process
SET "name=%~nx1"
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "name=!name:_XX_=_%vers%_!"
RENAME %1 "%name%"
ENDLOCAL
```